# How to get notified when a notification is notified

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent, accessibilityservice

I want to read/access/log the notifications fired on notification bar by other applications.

I searched `Intents` and `PendingIntents` a lot, but couldn't get a solution.

Does my application need to be notified when any notification is fired?

Or Does android system provide something to read notifications by the user-level applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got the answer.!!! Using [AccessibilityService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html#SERVICE_META_DATA)

```
public class NotificationService extends AccessibilityService {

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub.
//Code when the event is caught 
   }
@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub.

}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
      info.feedbackType = 1;
          info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
      info.notificationTimeout = 100; 
      setServiceInfo(info);
     }
}
```

And my Manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.test.notify"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <service android:name=".NotificationService" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter >
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
        </intent-filter>
     </service>
   </application>
 </manifest>
```

Enjoy Coding.!!! :)

Comment: The code is only to catch events related to notifications. On changing
`info.eventTypes = ` we can catch different type of events.

Comment: i am trying to get log in on service connected method, but it fails, does it require any permissions

Comment: @Calvin : You need to turn the Accessibility service manually from Settings (Settings -> Acccessibility )

Answer (score 7):

Starting with api 18 (android 4.3) it's possible:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

Very easy to use, but the user have to give permission to the app manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is not any API for access any notification. At least it would be hole in security. Only thing you can is catching some events, that causes notifications (like sms).

Answer (score 0):

A `Notification` is raised by sending an `Intent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
```

The `NotificationReceiver` catches the `Intent` and pops up a `Notification`.

It is perfectly possible to catch the same `Intent` in one of your applications using a [BroadCastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and filter on the `Intent` you want.

Comment: There is no intent for "notification bar state change" or "notification fired".

Comment: That is true, but the notifications are fired using Intents.. And Intents can be caught with a BroadCastReceiver. Afcourse, this all depends on what kind of Nofication you want to access.

Comment: Actually i want to log all the notifications. So i'm searching for a generic method to catch all the notifications.

Comment: @MartijnVanMierloo : this is not true. notifications are added to the notificationManager, which uses a System service, not a broadcast.