# is there a way to see the pop-ups / dialogs / notification seen in the android emulator?

Tags: android, dialog, popup, emulation, android-notifications

what I need to do is to read a pop-up or dialog seen in the emulator and be able to read the text in it.

Example, there is an available update for a particular app installed in your phone and it shows a notification at the top of your screen. I need to read that pop up/ dialog / notification and be able to read what it says, is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This might be what you are looking for to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429084/how-to-get-notified-when-a-notification-is-notified

Comment: @JuanAndrés Based on my understanding, what he want to get is the notification seen at the top of the screen. this isn't exactly what I'm looking for but this might help me a lot. Thanks!! :D