# To retrieve incoming notification details from whatsapp in android

Tags: android, notifications, message, whatsapp

How can I retrieve the name, message and time for any incoming notification on "whatsapp". Basically, I want to add up all incoming notification details in an array list. Please help me to get the explained code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to catch a 3rd party notification which requires a little more work. This SO question might help you to the right track.

[How to get notified when a notification is notified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429084/how-to-get-notified-when-a-notification-is-notified)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but still I am not able to retrieve the details of the notifications. I don't want to use Notification Listener as  it works over 4.3 only. :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using Accessibility Service  . Using this, you can listen to all notification on the notification bar. I listened to application-specification by adding the package name to the Accessibility Service service info , which in this case was com.whatsapp. I couldn't read the messages, but I get notified whenever a message arrives.

http://developer.android.com/training/accessibility/service.html#create

Comment: thanks.. but I need the details of notification like message, name and time of arrival of notification. Please help me to get these information