# How listen to incoming notification in android programity?

Tags: android, notifications

I want listen to incoming notifications and when i detect notification my app do somthing
How can i do this?
I search for this but i can't find answer
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class NotificationService extends AccessibilityService {

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub.
//Code when the event is caught 
   }
@Override
public void onInterrupt() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub.

}

@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
      info.feedbackType = 1;
          info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED;
      info.notificationTimeout = 100; 
      setServiceInfo(info);
     }
}
```

And my Manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.test.notify"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
     <service android:name=".NotificationService" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter >
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
        </intent-filter>
     </service>
   </application>
 </manifest>
```

founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429084/how-to-get-notified-when-a-notification-is-notified)

Comment: thanks bro :-)  I work on this code and complete this with TYPE_NOTIFICATION_STATE_CHANGED event to listen to incoming notifications

Answer (score 0):

NotificationListenerService

> A service that receives calls from the system when new notifications
>   are posted or removed, or their ranking changed.

Check from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html)

Comment: is there another way to do this on lower api?? for example api8